# Providing multiple languages for a website based on URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am thinking about how to provide multi language support for my personal website which i wrote using ExpressJS and NodeJS together with EJS as template engine. Currently, the site is only available in english but i would like to provide a german version, too. I would like to do it by using URL variables, so e.g.

**example.com/en/home -** displays the home page in english

**example.com/de/home -** displays the home page in german

A section with 2 buttons represented by the german and british flag should provide the possibility to change between those two languages.

## **What came already in mind?**

I already thought about making multiple folders inside my views directory, one each per language, containing all the same documents but in different languages and serving the proper document depending on the selected language inside the route. But this would lead to duplicating my HTTP documents and my routes and this is probably not a nice way to solve this, as it breaks the rule 'dont repeat yourself'.

Can anyone of you give me some advice to solve this in a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give an id to each button representing its language, then make a object like `{English: en, German: de}`

Comment: I dont quite get the content of that object and what to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to keep only a single template for your views because the amount of duplication would soon get out of hand.
You can make of this node package to do the internationalization thing  [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) which is integrated to work with expressJs

If you wanna know how it works, you can go through this awesome explanation of it by [Michael DeRazon](https://www.drzon.net/),  [i18n for Node + Express](https://www.drzon.net/posts/i18n-for-node-express/)